# jspdf and math formulas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, jspdf

I'm using jspdf in order to generate technical report.
I need to add math formulas.
The values in the formulas are generated by the script so I cannot use static images.

The only idea that comes in my mind is to play with a html5 canvas and than export a png

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MathJax to render the math formulas:

```
http://library.uoregon.edu/scis/blackboard/faq/instructors/i65.html
```

and try the jsPDF HTML renderer plugin to insert the HTML generated int your PDF documents.

Comment: MathJax is amazing, never heard it before. Unfortunately jspdf html plugin is at the early stages and does not work properly with the html emitted by MathJax

Comment: you too need to check MAthML

Comment: it does not seems very useful for my case

Comment: Actually I discover that jspdf does not support unicode so it is very hard to write formulas in a way different than use jpeg